# How to get text only from the parent element excluding child using protractor xpath function?

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get the text of the parent element alone that has one or more child. How do I get it using XPath?

(I am using the above XPath as an element identifier with the getText() method of the protractor)

The text of the parent element changes based on the user language selection, so I preferred to use the id attribute to identify the element

```
*<div class="header" id="Welcome_Label">
    "Welcome to the Mail page"
  <button class="btn" id="open">
    Open
    </button>
</div>*
```

xpath tried to get the parent text is

```
//div[@id='Welcome_Label']/*[not(self::button)]
```

I am expecting it to return the text parent text "Welcome to the Mail page", but it's returning "Welcome to the Mail page  Open".

Comment: `"Welcome to the Mail page"` is part of the first text node child of `div` element. But `*[not(self::button)]` will select just **elements**.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

If you are using the method that will get the text from only parent node.

**Python Implementation:**

```
def get_text_exclude_children(element):
return driver.execute_script(
    """
    var parent = arguments[0];
    var child = parent.firstChild;
    var textValue = "";
    while(child) {
        if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                textValue += child.textContent;
                child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return textValue;""",
    element).strip()
```

In you case you can call this as below.

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".header")
value = get_text_exclude_children(ele)
print (value)
```

**Java Implementation:**

```
public String get_text_exclude_children(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
    return (String) js.executeScript("var parent = arguments[0];"
                                    + "var child = parent.firstChild;"
                                    + " var textValue = ''; while(child) { "
                                            + "if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)"
                                                + " textValue += child.textContent;"
                                                + " child = child.nextSibling; "
                                                + "} return textValue;",element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, using just your code

```
//div/text()
```

Outputs:

> "Welcome to the Mail page"

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I use this XPath inside a xpath function of protractor which looks something like let text = element(by.xpath("//div/text()")).getText(), but when I use during runtime it throws an error Failed: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: Understood; you may want to edit your question to  clarify that and add anything else that may be useful for user trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
//div[@id='Welcome_Label']/text()[../*]
```

It selects all `text()` nodes at the `div` level if it has at least one element child.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I use this XPath inside a xpath function of protractor which looks something like let text = element(by.xpath("//div[@id='Welcome_Label']/text()[../*]")).getText(), but when I use during runtime it throws an error Failed: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element. –

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was found the following:: http://exploreselenium.com/selenium/exclude-text-content-of-child-elements-of-the-parent-element-in-selenium-webdriver/

Using that, I just added the following function, although in this case I'm using CSS instead of XPath.

```
async function getTextExcludingChildren(css: string) {
    return await browser.executeScript(`return $("${css}").clone().children().remove().end().text();`);
}
```